# Defining a group from edge set of graph

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory

[image]

I consider three islands represented by vertices V and the travel routes by ship are represented by the edges E. Here G=(V,E).

I consider the non-empty set E and define the binary operation $\oplus_t$ called Travel. If I do not move at all then it is given by $0$ which acts like the additive identity. Travel is defined by the following:

$$x \oplus_t y = z$$
$$x \oplus_t z = y$$
$$y \oplus_t z = x$$ 
$$y \oplus_t x = z$$
$$z \oplus_t y = x$$
$$z \oplus_t x = y$$

The operation travel makes E into a group (abelian group). 
This seems fine to me... but still I thought of verifying.

Besides, I would like to add more graph theory questions to this matter and maybe a couple of group theory questions. Any suggestions? (The questions could be based on matter found in Graph theory- Derek Allan Horton and John Clark).

Comment: Of course this attempt todefine a group structure works only if any two edges share a vertex ...

Comment: Yes, that is right. In case of a triangle, it works! Can you add something to what I have written?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen : One can conclude that for any complete graph, given the edge set , it is possible to obtain a group using the binary operation defined above.

Comment: This is slightly imprecise, in the sense that you are nit really "travelling" along $x$ etc, because your edges have no direction! Just thought I would point it out, incase you wanted to ponder something...

Comment: @user1729 : Is it not okay if my edges do not have direction? As pointed below, one could take them to be the shotest path travelled... Edges do not always have direction. Think about the case when an edge is represented by a bridge between two islands.

Comment: @Manasi I'll add this as an answer. In the answer which is there just now, the edges have direction.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, for an arbitrary graph, you can consider all paths starting at a particular node; this "path space" has some nice properties. By restricting to LOOPS that start and end at some particular node, you get the loopspace of the graph; there's a natural kind of "multiplication" in which you traverse one loop and then the other; the composition starts and ends at the basepoint, and hence is also a loop. There's no "inverse" in this situation though: you can't add something to a loop to make it the zero-step loop (the identity element). So it's a semigroup, and in general is nonabelian.

If your graph has some additional structure, like a filled-in triangle that you can "slide across", then you get a sense of equivalent loops -- called "homotopic loops" -- and the equivalence classes of loops have the same "multiplication" operation, except now there are inverses as well...and you've invented "the fundamental group of a finite simplicial complex", which is the starting point of many combinatorial topology books.

All this is to say: you're doing something interesting here, and tinkering with ideas like these isn't a bad thing at all!

Comment: I did not consider loops because I just felt that more questions could be asked if it was a simple/complete graph. So, I resorted to no movement = $0$.  However, there is an additive inverse here. You travel from Vertex A to C and then from C to A i.e $x \oplus_t x = 0$. Similarly, for y and z. Therefore, it is a group (or an abelian group).

Comment: I will look up homotopic loops and the fundamental group of finite simplicial complexes. I will see if some topology could be introduced in this matter as well!

Comment: Right: your "sum of two edges" would be, if we considered paths, something like "the shortest path that gets to the same place." The operation I described is a bit different, but much more deeply studied (for about the last 100 years!)

Comment: @Manasi It is worth pointing out that without the "filled in triangles" you get free groups, while with them you get precisely the finitely generated (presented?) groups (assuming the graph is finite).

Comment: @user1729 and John : Thanks. Will think.